# Activity Monitor No Longer displays columns

Tags: catalina, activity-monitor

I have a Mac Mini (late 2012) running Catalina (10.15.3).  I can't remember when I first noticed it, but for a while now, I cannot sort Activity Monitor's columns.  This is essentially what it looks like:

[image]

I've tried to find some way if I can perhaps reset its preferences, but google is not my friend.

Can someone help?

Comment: Same question as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380385/activity-monitor-columns-missing, and I recommend [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386850) answer. Basically some bug causes the Process Name column to balloon, often beyond the window boundary. One can scroll to the right and drag the column edge back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably can just go to the View menu (the one between Edit and Window), select Columns and add additional columns again (or switch to a simple process view and back to hierarchical).

If this doesn't work, you can remove preferences by

- Quitting Activity Monitor
- `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ActivityMonitor.plist*`

Comment: Any clue why the simple method without the terminal command doesn't work?

Comment: @Pulakesh Unfortunately not.

Comment: I may know; columns are not hidden, each was resized to screen size (at least in my case), and I don't believe in accidents (either it's intentional or yet another MacOSX bug).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try scrolling to the right?