# Activity Monitor Showing Nothing

Tags: mac, activity-monitor

My activity monitor no longer shows me anything after my computer automatically restarted.

[image]

Previously I tried some tricks to reset the activity monitor such as this [Activity Monitor columns missing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380385/activity-monitor-columns-missing)

Does anyone know any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted again, normally?

Comment: Computers in this century are so badly designed :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tetsujin's suggestion.

Following an automatic restart, a second intentional restart fixed this error.